# Show full question or excerpt in suggested edits page for tag-only edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

It's difficult to determine whether a suggested edit that consists of only modifications to tags is reasonable without the context of the question. For instance, today I saw this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/8300) and had to click through to the question to determine whether it was worth approving or rejecting.

Why not show at least an excerpt from the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

completed, to be deployed later today .....